# how to I lock just the x or y axis of a div?

Tags: css, html

I made a small window for a tools menu but because I had to use an iframe to solve a specific issue it now scrolls left and right. I still neet it to scroll up and down but disabled the left and right.

```
<div id="map-tools">
                <form autocomplete="off" id=vis-select style="height:100%">
                <ul id="tools-list" data-role="listview" style="height:100%">
                    <li id="tools-4">
                            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                                <g:if test="${site.javaScriptModules.find{it.fileName=='google-map.js'} }">
                                   <input name="radio-choice-v-2" id="google-map-module" value="" <g:if test="${site.defaultVisualization?.fileName == 'google-map.js'}">checked="checked"</g:if> type="radio" data-messages="switch-vis" data-switch-vis="#google-map" >
                                    <label for="google-map-module">Google Map</label>
                                </g:if>
                                <g:if test="${site.javaScriptModules.find{it.fileName=='google-earth.js'} }">
                                    <input name="radio-choice-v-2" id="google-earth-module" value="" <g:if test="${site.defaultVisualization?.fileName == 'google-earth.js'}">checked="checked"</g:if> type="radio" data-active="false" data-messages="switch-vis" data-switch-vis="#google-earth" >    
                                    <label for="google-earth-module">Google Earth</label>
                                </g:if>
                                <g:if test="${site.javaScriptModules.find{it.fileName=='cesium.js'} }">
                                    <input name="radio-choice-v-2" id="cesium-earth-module" value="" <g:if test="${site.defaultVisualization?.fileName == 'cesium.js'}">checked="checked"</g:if> type="radio" data-messages="switch-vis" data-switch-vis="#cesium-earth" >  
                                    <label for="cesium-earth-module">Cesium Earth</label>
                                </g:if>     
                            </fieldset>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </form>
                <iframe id="tools-cover-earth" class="cover" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div>
```

this is the css

```
#map-tools{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 44px;
    background:#ffffff;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 320px;
    height: 0px;
}

.cover{
    background:#ffffff;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Comment: sorry. im new to this site. when i past the code in it looks weird

Comment: Put code in the question and properly format it. And make sure it is *everything* relevant. An empty `<ui>` cannot possibly be all you have.

Comment: I added the overflow: hidden in a few different places and is didn't seem to do anything

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6ADM/ - it doesn't scroll to right or left here

Answer (score 0):

You may need to play with `overflow` in css but for better answers you need to include your whole problematic code with context. `<div><ui></ui></div>` tells us nothing.